# Fourier Transformation for $x[n]=(-1)^{n}$

Tags: fourier-transform

I am trying to to do a Fourier Transformation with the following [started work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnAqe.jpg) :

with the question on the paper on the third step, why is the conversion from $$(-1)^n= e^{-j\pi n}$$ when I thought it was $$(-1)^n = (e^{j\pi})^n = e^{j\pi n} $$ Also I am a little confused what to do from the last step. I know the final answer will be $$ X(e^{jw}) = 2\pi \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \delta[\omega - (2k+1)\pi] $$ but I'm confused after the last step shown in the image above.

Comment: $e^{-i\pi n} = e^{-i \pi n}\cdot 1 = e^{-i\pi n}e^{2i\pi n} = e^{-i\pi n + 2i\pi n} = e^{i\pi n}$.

Comment: so are you implying that $e^{-i\pi n} $ and $ e^{i\pi n} $ are interchangeable?

Comment: Yes, they are equal. To see it another way, $e^{-i\pi n} = (e^{-i\pi})^n = (-1)^n$, and $e^{i\pi n} = (e^{i\pi})^n = (-1)^n$. In other words, we're simply exploiting the fact that $e^{-i\pi} = e^{i\pi}$. This in turn because $\cos(-\pi) = \cos(\pi) = -1$ and $\sin(-\pi) = \sin(\pi) = 0$.

Comment: oh thank you so much that makes so much more sense ^.^